# Saving System.Graphics to bitmap not working

Tags: c#, system.graphics

I've created program for drawing. It uses System.graphics to draw rectangles etc. on panel1 in form.
[Graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rvffQ.png)
Mouse draw event:
[Draw](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wBeO1.png)
I want to get art from panel1 as a bitmap, tried this code:

```
using (var bmp = new Bitmap(panel1.Width, panel1.Height))
{
    panel1.DrawToBitmap(bmp, new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height));
    bmp.Save("output.png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
}
```

but it generates background color of panel1 in image

Comment: Don't create `Graphics` objects in arbitrary functions. Use the object passed in the `Paint` event and draw only in an event handler of this event. This will also solve the save-to-file problem. And please include the code as text, not as an image.

Answer (score 1):

Add a handler to the Paint event of the panel somewhere (e.g. form constructor):

```
panel1.Paint += panel1_Paint;
```

[Re]draw any graphics in the event:

```
void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{            
    DrawLine(e.Graphics);
}
```

When saving, your code should work just fine:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (var bmp = new Bitmap(panel1.Width, panel1.Height))
    {
        panel1.DrawToBitmap(bmp, new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height));
        bmp.Save("c:\\temp\\output.png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    }
}
```